# Назначить администратором беседы ВК через API

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, api, вконтакте

Как назначать и разжаловать администраторов в беседах ВК через API? В Kate Mobile это реализовано только непонятно как, метода найти не могу

Comment: Что-то я не вижу ничего похожего в списке методов API: https://vk.com/dev.php?method=methods Вы уверены, что в этом приложении это сделано именно через API?

Comment: @AK если в приложении это сделано не через API то как? При авторизации в нем получается ключ от API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я и думал, есть скрытый метод для этого, который не описан в документации, но в логах ВК я его нашел, представляю вашему вниманию: messages.setMemberRole